# Bootcamp and Windows 7 - Mounting the .iso onto a blank DVD-R

Tags: bootcamp, windows, disk-utility, mount

So im trying to install Windows 7 Ultimate via Bootcamp on my Macbook Pro 13"....Managed to partition the HDD but for some reason whenever I click install, the Macbook restarts and I'm met with a black screen with white text that read something along the lines of "This is not a bootable device" or something like that.

Now i should note that Windows is on a DVD-R, so i thought maybe the DVD-R was damaged so i created an .cdr image of the DVD-R via the disk utility and then changed the file name to .iso as stated on this website - http://www.ehow.com/how_2093946_create-disk-image-mac-osx.html.

But now I'm wondering how do I mount the .iso onto another DVD-R? Or am i going about the entire thing completely wrong? In other words, help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you burning the ISO file on to a DVD-R as a file or as a DVD image? There's a big difference between the two. Only the latter method works.

To burn a DVD from the ISO image, follow this Apple guide:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2087

Answer (score 1):

The ISO file is a virtual DVD, not a file that needs to be burned onto one. To turn this virtual DVD into a real one, put a blank in your machine and right click the ISO and select to open it with Disk Utility. Click Burn on the top bar and follow the on-screen prompts.